# Move TD Element and reorder with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to reorder table elements to set a new order.  What I thought would work with grabbing the tr wont work since it grabs the entire piece being moved, including the Order Number.

How do I go about grabbing child tds of the href td?

Last, I have been trying to use replaceWith() but not sure about the reordering with items below the one being moved.

How can I reorder the rest of the items?
Moving 4 -> 1, 1 becomes 2, 2 -> becomes 3...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var rowFirstChoice;
var rowSecondChoice;
$('.trigger').click(function () {
    if(rowFirstChoice==undefined) {

        $('.trigger').text('HERE');
        rowFirstChoice = $(this).closest('tr');
        rowFirstChoice.find('a').html('MOVE');

    } else if (rowSecondChoice==undefined) {
        rowSecondChoice = $(this).closest('tr');
        //var tmpChoice = rowSecondChoice;
        rowSecondChoice.replaceWith(rowFirstChoice);
        //Notes
        //How can I reorder the rest of the items?
        //i.e. 4 -> 1, 1 becomes 2, 2 -> becomes 3...
        //END Notes
        $('.trigger').text('MOVE');
        rowFirstChoice = undefined;
        rowSecondChoice = undefined;
    }
});
});
```

I have been attempting this in a JSFIDDLE.
http://jsfiddle.net/ndsumonu/7/

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `before` to move the one row before the other.

```
$(this).closest('tr').before(rowFirstChoice);
```

Then to re-number, you can use `text` with a function to set the value:

```
$('#customList > tbody > tr > td:first-child').text(function(i){
    return i + 1;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ndsumonu/11/

Comment: Stack snippets wont load for me at all right now or I would have added one.

Comment: This is pretty cool!  I am looking into before() now.  I didnt know that about jquery.   I might have to add additional logic since i cant move certain items, i.e. lower(1,2,3) numbered items next to higher(2,3,4) items.  reading up on before... but yeah items next to eachother if the lower is selected first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rowFirstChoice;
    var rowSecondChoice;
    $('.trigger').click(function () {
        if(rowFirstChoice==undefined) {            
            $('.trigger').text('HERE');            
            this.innerHTML = "MOVE";
            rowFirstChoice = $(this).parent().siblings().find("> input");
        } else if (rowSecondChoice==undefined) {            
            rowSecondChoice = $(this).parent().siblings().find("input");        

            var firstValue = rowFirstChoice.val();
            rowFirstChoice.val(rowSecondChoice.val());
            rowSecondChoice.val(firstValue);

            $('.trigger').text('MOVE');
            rowFirstChoice = undefined;
            rowSecondChoice = undefined;
        }
    });
});
```

This will swap the values of the inputs, thus maintaining order numbers and ids in place.

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndsumonu/15/)